# slipstream Visual Studio 2010 service pack 1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, slipstream

Visual studio 2010 is great and SP 1 is adding flavor to it.

I am planning to install Visual studio 2010 with SP 1 in quite a few system. Visual studio takes only about 20 mins to install but SP1 takes 45 - 60 mins to install.

I was wondering if there is a way to slipstream sp1 into VS 2010 setup so that it installs as a part of Visual studio 2010 setup.

There is no VS 2010 along with SP1 setup from MSDN. I looked for it and I don't think there is any plan to have any such release.

So I was wondering if any superuser could guide me on how to slipstream sp1 into the VS 2010 setup.

Comment: I'm surprised SP1 takes that long to install. You are installing from the ISO/offline installer correct?

Comment: I think it takes that much for sp1 for everyone , atleast that is what the ms forums says. yes I am installing iso of sp1 about 1.5 gb from 'http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23691' at the bottom of page.

Comment: VS + SP1 on our VMs take about 30 minutes from start to finish.  This includes installing the Silverlight SDK, Resharper and about 10 other extensions. Or maybe it is because I'm such a bada$$ admin that my machines are running like FIRE!

Comment: My systems are just i3 with 4gb of ddr3... so that might be the prob.. But even then 30 mins is way too smooth. There are plenty of people like me for whom it takes about 45-60 mins . source : blogs.msdn.com . And seems many are requesting for slipstreamed version but its not out yet (don't know about future )

Answer (score 0):

[Installing Visual Studio 2010 RTM and Service Pack 1 together](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/setup/installing-visual-studio-2010-rtm-and-service-pack-1-together/)

Answer (score -1):

I have not gotten any SP1 on internet separate from visual studio 2010. You can download complete ISO from Microsoft website that include SP1.

As i have seen on stackoverflow question you can update this with some patches.. and what this SP1 contains..

The VS2010 SP1, is actually an update (bug fixes) for Visual Studio 2010. This does not contain updates for the redistributables because there aren't any yet. However, older SP for VS2008 did include updates for the .net Framework redistributables.

check this Stack Overflow question details and updates details..

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655962/difference-between-visual-studio-redistributable-and-visual-studio-sp1

```
    If you have VS 2010 installed, then these patches may update your 
visual studio 2010 for bugfix matters.
```

Possibly it will reduce installation time..

Comment: Question is not about redistributables.